# Does PRISM for Xamarin Forms support the new Shell / URI based navigation?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I was searching for an article on the net about this, however I couldn't find anything.

Does PRISM for Xamarin Forms support the newer Shell / URI based navigation API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no support for Shell (and navigation) with Prism in Xamarin.Forms. For future investigation and news about this topic, there is an open issue on the Prism Library GitHub repository.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1809), and you can also read the discussions about these topics.